# How to count the number of lines in a text file in Octave?

Tags: octave

And don't say `fskipl` because it doesn't work!!!

`fskipl undefined`.

Comment: What version of Octave are you using? I have `fskipl` in 3.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have `fgetl`? If so, you can do this little loop:

```
f = fopen('myfile.txt', 'rt');
ctr = 0;
ll = fgetl(f);
while (!isnumeric(ll)) %# fgetl returns -1 when it hits eof. But you can't do ll != -1 because blank lines make it barf
    ctr = ctr+1;
    ll = fgetl(f);
end
fclose(f);
```

Otherwise, you could do some hack like:

```
f = fopen('myfile.txt', 'rb');
ctr = 0;
[x, bytes] = fread(f, 8192); %# use an 8k intermediate buffer, change this value as desired
while (bytes > 0)
    ctr = ctr + sum(x == 10); %# 10 is '\n'
    [x, bytes] = fread(f, 8192);
end
fclose(f);
```

10 is the ASCII code for the newline character. But this seems unreliable, especially if you come across a file that uses carriage return instead of newline.

Comment: Actually I am using `fgetl`. Counting lines with `fgetl` seems pretty crude (and inefficient). I was wondering if there was a better way...

Comment: Thanks for explaining about `ll != -1`. I was getting an error and couldn't figure out why. Why does it have a problem with blank lines?

Comment: Try typing `'' != -1` at the prompt - you'll see that the answer is empty, not true.