# Reading specific column from CSV file in matlab

Tags: matlab, csv

I am trying to read a CSV file in matlab. I just want to read the second column but the code below prints out everything on  CSV file. What parameters or functions I have to introduce to make it read just the second column

```
FILENAME = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Results.csv';

fid = fopen(FILENAME, 'rt');
a = textscan(fid, '%s', 'HeaderLines',1,'Delimiter',',');
fclose(fid);
celldisp(a)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. Using `cvsread`:
   Assuming you have `N` rows in the file<sup>1</sup>:

   ```
   a = csvread( FILENAME, 0, 1, [0 1 N-1 1 ] );
   ```
2. You might also consider `xlsread`

   ```
   a = xlsread( FILENAME, 'B:B' );
   ```

   See specific [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html#bthgbe6) on the `xlsread` doc.
3. Another option is `dlmread`

   ```
   a = dlmread( FILENAME, ',', [0 1 N-1 1] );
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup> - A nice (and fast) way to count the number of lines in the file in Matlab can be found in [this answer by Rody Oldenhuis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12176649/1714410).

Comment: I just put N=10 and got this Warning: R and C should match RANGE(1:2).  Use DLMREAD(FILE,DELIMITER,RANGE) instead.
> In dlmread at 110
  In csvread at 54
  In read at 6
??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 2) ==> DFA S

Error in ==> csvread at 54
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c, rng);

Error in ==> read at 6
a = csvread( FILENAME, 0, 0, [0 1 10 1 ] );

Comment: ??? Undefined function or variable 'N'.

Error in ==> read at 6
csvread( FILENAME, 0, 1, [0 1 N 1] );

Comment: @Zara if you have an `"undefined ... 'N'"` error - this means that `N` is not defined. Haven't you set it to `10`???

Comment: FILENAME = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Results.csv';
N=10;
fid = fopen(FILENAME, 'rt');
a = csvread( FILENAME, 0, 0, [0 1 N 1 ] );
fclose(fid);
celldisp(a)

Comment: I have used the above code and it gives me the error I have mentioned in forst comment

Comment: @Zara why `fopen` and `fclose`? you don't need to do this `cvsread` does it for you.

Comment: FILENAME = 'C:\Users\Desktop\Results.csv';
N=10;
a = csvread( FILENAME, 0, 0, [0 1 N 1 ] );

celldisp(a)

Comment: Warning: R and C should match RANGE(1:2).  Use DLMREAD(FILE,DELIMITER,RANGE) instead.
> In dlmread at 110
  In csvread at 54
  In read at 3
??? Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 2) ==> DFA S

Error in ==> csvread at 54
    m=dlmread(filename, ',', r, c, rng);

Error in ==> read at 3
a = csvread( FILENAME, 0, 0, [0 1 N 1 ] );

Comment: Error using ==> dlmread at 145
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 2) ==> DFA S

Error in ==> read at 3
a = dlmread( FILENAME, ',', [0 1 N-1 1] );

Comment: I don't want to read the first row as it includes the headings. I want to start from 2nd row till end and read all the elements present in 2nd column.

Comment: @zara If you have a header row in the file, you might need to skip it: `a = dlmread( FILENAME, ',', [1 1 N-1 1] );`

Comment: @Zara please read the help section of the commands you are trying to run, so you can resolve these error by yourself.

Comment: How can you find `N` dynamically? - - I for instance notice that it changes dynamically for me. - - How can you remove empty cell tail in the end of the list?