# reading data from csv files with `textscan` in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, csv, import

[**Edited**:] I have a file `data2007a.csv` and I copied and pasted (using TextEdit in MacBook) the first consecutive few lines to a new file `datatest1.csv` for testing:

```
Nomenclature,ReporterISO3,ProductCode,ReporterName,PartnerISO3,PartnerName,Year,TradeFlowName,TradeFlowCode,TradeValue in 1000 USD
S3,ABW,0,Aruba,ANT,Netherlands Antilles,2007,Export,6,448.91
S3,ABW,0,Aruba,ATG,Antigua and Barbuda,2007,Export,6,0.312
S3,ABW,0,Aruba,CHN,China,2007,Export,6,24.715
S3,ABW,0,Aruba,COL,Colombia,2007,Export,6,95.885
S3,ABW,0,Aruba,DOM,Dominican Republic,2007,Export,6,11.432
```

I wanted to use `textscan` to read it into MATLAB with only columns 2,3,5 (starting from the second row) and I wrote the following code

```
clc,clear all
fid = fopen('datatest1.csv');
data = textscan(fid,'%*s %s %d %*s %s %*[^\n]',...
       'Delimiter',',',...
       'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);
```

But I ended up with only the second row of columns 2,3 and 5:

[image]

---

I then keep the first row in `data2007a.csv` and selected several others to saved as `datatest2.csv`:

```
Nomenclature,ReporterISO3,ProductCode,ReporterName,PartnerISO3,PartnerName,Year,TradeFlowName,TradeFlowCode,TradeValue in 1000 USD
S3,ABW,1,Aruba,USA,United States,2007,Export,6,1.392
S3,ABW,1,Aruba,VEN,Venezuela,2007,Export,6,5633.157
S3,ABW,2,Aruba,ANT,Netherlands Antilles,2007,Export,6,310.734
S3,ABW,2,Aruba,USA,United States,2007,Export,6,342.42
S3,ABW,2,Aruba,VEN,Venezuela,2007,Export,6,63.722
S3,AGO,0,Angola,DEU,Germany,2007,Export,6,105.334
S3,AGO,0,Angola,ESP,Spain,2007,Export,6,8533.125
```

And I wrote:

```
clc,clear all
fid = fopen('datatest2.csv');
data = textscan(fid,'%*s %s %d %*s %s %*[^\n]',...
       'Delimiter',',',...
       'HeaderLines',1);
fclose(fid);  
data{1}
```

It gives exactly what I wanted:
[image]
[image]

When I use the same code for my original data file `data2007a.csv`, it goes as in the first case.

What is going wrong and how can I fix it?

---

[**Added**:] If one replicates my experiments<sup>1</sup>, one can find that both cases work and the problem does not exist! I really don't know what is going on.

<sup>1</sup> For "replicate" I mean copy-and-paste the data given above and save it as two new files, say, `datatest4a.csv` and `datatest4b.csv`. I used `visdiff('datatest1.csv', 'datatest4a.csv')` to compare two files and it returned:

> [image]

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible. I doubt that you're using a different file in MATLAB and your actual file is different. In your post, you said that you had a file named `data.csv` but in MATLAB, you opened  `datatest.csv`. I doubt that this is not just a typo

Comment: @Sardar_Usama: Thanks for pointing that out. It is indeed a typo. I will edit it right away.

Comment: You missed the main point. Your problem isn't reproducible

Comment: @Sardar_Usama: Sorry, I don't quite understand your comment. Would you elaborate what you mean by "problem is not reproducible"?

Comment: That it does not reproduce the result that you showed in the screenshot. Rather it produces the result that you're looking for, i.e. it contains all the rows (starting from the second row) of the specified columns

Comment: Was your original csv file created on a different system?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama: I edited the question. Thanks again. It seems that something weird happened. (One cannot reproduce the problem.) I might ask a follow-up question later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how you fixed it, I think this is an end-of-line character issue. This sometimes comes up when moving text files between Windows and Unix based systems, as they use different conventions.

When you add `%*[^\n]` to the end of a `textscan` format, as you have here. it means to skip everything to the end of line. But if it expects a specific end of line character, and can't find one, it will skip everything to the end of the *file*. This would explain why you get one row correctly read and then nothing else.

If you don't specify what the end of line character is, Matlab appears to default to... something... in this not very clear specification in the help:

> The default end-of-line sequence is \n, \r, or \r\n, depending on the contents of your file.

One way to try and cure this without having to create a new file would be to add this `'EndOfLine', '\r\n'` to your `textscan` call:

> If you specify '\r\n', then textscan treats any of \r, \n, and the
>   combination of the two (\r\n) as end-of-line characters.

This will hopefully handle most standard(ish) EOL conventions. It is likely that copy-pasting and saving with a different bit of software than was originally used to create the file changed the end of line characters such that Matlab was able to recognise them.