# How to add data of csv column to G.Edges

Tags: matlab

I have a csv file in with these column

```
column1      column2      column3
  1            2            3
```

and G.Edges in this format

```
   1            2           3         4 
EndNodes      Weight      Name     Distance
```

what I would like to do is read the grocerydb.csv file and add all the data in column2 of the csv file to column 5 of G.Edges

i tried this code

```
 fid = fopen('grocerydb.csv');
 productUPC = textscan(fid,1);
 productName = textscan(fid,'%s',2);
 fclose(fid);
```

but it reads the second row not the column. 
I have review some answers to similar questions such as this [Reading specific column from CSV file in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440689/reading-specific-column-from-csv-file-in-matlab). which gave instruction for rows, what I want is a column data not row

how can i implement reading the second column and add it to G.Edges?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading specific column from CSV file in matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440689/reading-specific-column-from-csv-file-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the G.Edges is a table in MATLAB for this makes life easier. As far as I know, MATLAB do not like csv files as Python do. So, we read csv as a table. Suppose that we have a table TARGETTable with variables acct, num_courses_visited, total_minutes_visited, and lessons_completed which like your G.Edges., Furthermore, there are many columns in a csv file ‘daily-engagement.csv’, we just need the data in second column utc_date. The csv file is very large, we need a few lines. At last, we note that the column utc_date is data, we should transform it to right type in MATLAB.

```
filename = 'D:\Temp\daily-engagement.csv';
delimiter = ',';
startRow = 2;
endRow = 9;
formatSpec = '%*q%{yyyy-MM-dd}D%*s%*s%*s%*s%[^\n\r]';
fileID = fopen(filename,'r');
dataArray = textscan(fileID, formatSpec, endRow-startRow+1, 'Delimiter', delimiter, 'TextType', 'string', 'HeaderLines', startRow-1, 'ReturnOnError', false, 'EndOfLine', '\r\n');
fclose(fileID);
dailyengagement = table(dataArray{1:end-1}, 'VariableNames', {'utc_date'});
```

Now, we can combine this dailyengagement to TARGETTable.

```
TARGETTable = [TARGETTable dailyengagement]
```